# C# binding object to string

Tags: c#, string, object, dynamic, binding

I want to bind a dynamic object to a string like replacing the instance.field in string to the real value of the instance.

See my code below to understand:

```
String body = "My Name is: model.Name";
Model model = new Model();
model.Name = "Mohammed";
String result = ReplaceMethod(body,model);
// result is, My Name is: Mohammed
```

Note: I want to use this procedure in big string value with too many fields. Thanks.

Comment: you need at least to wrap you substring model.Name into something like {model.Name}, then using regex find all these, get second part after dot and then use reflection to get field/property value

Comment: Why so complicated? Can't you use [string interpolation](https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-interpolation)?

Comment: @TobiasTheel actually there can be lots of reasons, for example build server does not support C# 6.0, or all team is using another VS version

Comment: @Alexey it's true there could be lots of reasons, that is why i ask. Maybe this is also a [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). So it would be good to get to know the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use perfix in string like "model.Name", I would go right away with {Name}.
What we need is to find all of them, Regex can help us with this.

Try this method, check comments:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String body = "My Name is: {Name} {LastName}";
        Model model = new Model();
        model.Name = "Mohammed";
        model.LastName = "LastName";
        String result = ReplaceMethod(body, model);
    }

    private static string ReplaceMethod(string body, Model model)
    {
        // can't name property starting with numbers, 
        // but they are possible
        Regex findProperties = new Regex(@"{([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)}");

        // order by desc, since I want to replace all substrings correctly
        // after I replace one part length of string is changed 
        // and all characters at Right are moved forward or back
        var res = findProperties.Matches(body)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.Index);

        foreach (Match item in res)
        {
            // get full substring with pattern "{Name}"
            var allGroup = item.Groups[0];

            //get first group this is only field name there
            var foundPropGrRoup = item.Groups[1];
            var propName = foundPropGrRoup.Value;

            object value = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                // use reflection to get property
                // Note: if you need to use fields use GetField
                var prop = typeof(Model).GetProperty(propName);

                if (prop != null)
                {
                    value = prop.GetValue(model, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO Logging here
            }

            // remove substring with pattern
            // use remove instead of replace, since 
            // you may have several the same string
            // and insert what required
            body = body.Remove(allGroup.Index, allGroup.Length)
                .Insert(allGroup.Index, value.ToString());

        }

        return body;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension based on Alexy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082821/8058709).

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string BindTo<T>(this string body, T model) where T : class
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"{([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)}");

        var matches = regex.Matches(body).Cast<Match>()
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.Index);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var fullMatch = match.Groups[0];

            var propName = match.Groups[1].Value;

            object value = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                // use reflection to get property
                // Note: if you need to use fields use GetField
                var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);

                if (prop != null)
                {
                    value = prop.GetValue(model, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO Logging here
            }

            // remove substring with pattern
            // use remove instead of replace, since 
            // you may have several the same string
            // and insert what required
            body = body.Remove(fullMatch.Index, fullMatch.Length)
                .Insert(fullMatch.Index, value.ToString());

        }

        return body;
    }

}
```

That way you can call it like this.

```
body = body.BindTo(model);
```

**Edit:**
You could also use [Mustache#](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp) which is based on the awesome [mustache](https://mustache.github.io) library.

In situations where you need much fewer properties to be bound, you could use tools like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) or create anonymous objects as you go along. For example:

```
body = body.BindTo(new { model.Name, model.Email });
```

Best of luck!